# opencv installation for linux ubuntu issues

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to install opencv following this tutorial,

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Unfortunately, I can't get the path variable for opencv4 to work after using cmake, make and install etc.

Is there a way to do this easily? Has anyone ahd this issue?

Comment: Raspberry, pc, etc?

Comment: unless you changed the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` before, there is no reason to fiddle with the path. what is the exact problem here ?